# communication between two sibling components without using service in angular2/4

Tags: angular

I have a two sibling component like app-event and app-object inside one root component and I have array of objects inside app-object component ,now i want to pass that array of object in app-event sibling component, how can i do that in angualr2/4 in very simple way?

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <app-object></app-object>
        <app-event></app-event>
      </div>
  </div>
```

this is my model file

```
export class dataObject{

  constructor(public item:string, public amount : number, public available:boolean){
     }
  }
```

this is app-object component ts file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { dataObject} from './app-object.model'

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-object',
     templateUrl: './app-object.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app-object.component.css']
   })

   export class AppObjectComponent implements OnInit {

 data:dataObject[]=[new dataObject('itemA',45,true), new dataObject('itemB',58,false)];

  constructor() {
  console.log(this.data);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 }
```

Now the app-event component ts file code where i want to have the data of app-object file(data variable-array of object)

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-event',
 templateUrl: './app-event.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app-event.component.css']
})

  export class AppEventComponent implements OnInit {

  // here inside this class i want to have data of app-object component....

     constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: i don't know why wouldn't you use a service but other option is to go through their common parent component. so, each sibling emmits events containing variables of interest (through @Output() params) and then those are bound to another sibling as @Input() params.

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-object #obj></app-object>
<app-event [data]="obj.data"=></app-event>
```

`AppEventComponent` needs

```
@Input()
data:dataObject[];
```

for this to work.

Comment: Gunter, this will work, of course, but just as a side question, is it ever a good practice to make one sibling dependant on other? wouldn't it make more sense to have consistent, generic interfaces on each sibling which are then tied together through parent in whatever logical way is required for that particular context/parent? (refering to my comment to the initial question). tnx

Comment: hey, can you explain bit what you have done above as a solution because i have implemente as you mentioned but got undefined in console.

Comment: `@Input()`s are not yet set in the constructor. You'd need to move the `console.log()` to `ngOnInit() { ... }`.

I think with my approach you don't make anything dependent. `#obj` is just a reference variable and the `@Input()` just says that the component depends on data and it can come from anywhere. Therefore you don't have any tight coupling in component code.

Comment: I am declaring @Input()
data:dataObject[];   in app-event component and tried loging that data inside its constructor method....there got undefined......,in here example my purpose is to iterate through the data object using ngFor in app-event component element and display inside it,So would it be possible using your approach?I am new to angular2 and practicing now.

Comment: oh sorry gunter,as you replied i got data in console by loging it inside ngOninit() method.thanks.

Comment: also, now i used data(array of obj) directly in  ngFor  inside app-event div....it works fine,thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewChild` to achieve this

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <app-object></app-object>
        <app-event></app-event>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Create two `ViewChild() objects` as below

```
@ViewChild(AppObjectComponent) appObjectComponent : AppObjectComponent;
@ViewChild(AppEventComponent) appEventComponent : AppEventComponent;
```

Declare the variables as public so that it can be accessed from here.

In your AppObjectComponent

```
arrayVariable:any[];
```

In your AppEventComponent

```
array2:any[]
```

The method in your parent component will be as

```
someEvent(){
    this.appObjectComponent.arrayVariable = this.appEventComponent.array2 ;
}
```